How do I ask latex to start numbering from the title page?
This is my MWE.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{\bfseries Thesis\\
{\Large \bfseries The University of Manchester}}
\author{Jalinne}
\date{September 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\par\vfill\noindent Word Count: 999

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\end{document}

How do I start numbering the page from the title page and not the table of contents?

Off-topic: top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in may be expressed more succinctly as margin=1in.

Redefine titlepage, which is the culprit as it does \setcounter{page}{1}.
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}

\renewenvironment{titlepage}
  {\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}}
  {\clearpage}

\doublespacing

\title{\bfseries Thesis\\
{\Large \bfseries The University of Manchester}}
\author{Jalinne}
\date{September 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\par\vfill\noindent Word Count: 999

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\end{document}



I suggest you load the report class with the option notitlepage, i.e.,
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}

If you're surmising that titlepage is the default option for the report class, you would be correct.
If you don't want to actually show the number "1" at the bottom of the title page, be sure to issue the instruction \thispagestyle{empty} immediately after \maketitle.


Just for fun:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{\bfseries Thesis\\
{\Large \bfseries The University of Manchester}}
\author{Jalinne}
\date{September 2024}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][s]{\textwidth}
  \maketitle
\end{minipage}%
\thispagestyle{plain}% if desired

\tableofcontents
\par\vfill\noindent Word Count: 999

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\end{document}

